# How to dynamically display/copy characters being typed in a textbox?

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is out of curiosity. I want to dynamically show in a label the characters being typed in a text box. I have set the text box mode to password, so, as the user enters the password, I want to display/copy the characters the user is entering and show them in the label below. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: using TextChanged event?

Comment: No.. i don want to use text changed event. thats why i have specified dynamically.

Comment: I thought the same as Ian.  Rakesh can you explain a little more by what you mean by "dynamically" that makes the TextChanged  event unacceptable?

Comment: @Rakesh "Dynamically" really has no meaning in regards to this question and definitely does not rule out using events.

Comment: I took it as 'while I type -  do it'. TextChanged isn't dynamic - its postback driven.

Comment: with the event i can copy the text and show it. Not a problem. i want to show the characters as and when the user enters the characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Keyup. Keypress is fired before value is updated. On each keypress read the value and assign to another item. Something like this assuming jQuery usage in your web page

```
$('#pwd').keyup(function() {
    var pwd= this.value;
    console.log(pwd);
    $("#output").val(pwd);
});
```

Comment: Thank you @adam for understanding the question and for providing the solution.